# How to put a variable into function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put a variable into a function which is dateStr when I do alert(dateStr) it gives me 2 3:5:58(2days 3hours 5mins 58seconds) but it is not working in function. Here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <!--=============================datetimepicker ================-->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

    <!--=============================countdown timer================-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>jquery countDownTimer Demo reverse countdown clock</title>
    <meta name="description" content="reverse clock plugin for jQuery.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="jQuery, plugin, count down">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../LIB/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/jquery.countdownTimer.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h3><u>Reverse countdown till a specific future date from today.</u><br/>(for eg:- 2018/01/01 00:00:00)</h3>
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
            <input type="text" id="date"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary start">Start</button>
        </div>
        </br>
        <table style="border:0px;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8"><span id="future_date"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.start').click(function(){

            var date = jQuery("#date").val();

            time = date.split(' ')[1];

            date = date.split(' ')[0];

            var firstDate = {day: date.split('/')[0], hours:time.split(':')[0], minutes: time.split(':')[1], seconds: time.split(':')[2]};

            var sDate = new Date();

            var secondDate = {day: sDate.getDate(), hours:sDate.getHours(), minutes: sDate.getMinutes(), seconds: sDate.getSeconds()};

            var subtime = function(fDate , tDate){
            var date = Math.abs(parseInt(fDate.day) - tDate.day);
            var hours = Math.abs(parseInt(fDate.hours) - tDate.hours);
            var minutes = Math.abs(parseInt(fDate.minutes) - tDate.minutes);
            var seconds = Math.abs(parseInt(fDate.seconds) - tDate.seconds);
            return {date: date, hours: hours, minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds};
            };

            var diff = subtime(firstDate, secondDate);

            var dateStr = diff.date + " " + diff.hours + ":" + diff.minutes + ":" + diff.seconds;
            alert(dateStr);


            jQuery('#future_date').countdowntimer({
        //          dateAndTime : "5 00:00:00"‚
                    dateAndTime : dateStr‚ // I want dateAndTime dateStr like the above dateAndTime
                    size : "lg",
                });
            });
            });
        </script>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
          });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now this is my full code with html.

Comment: Please add an exact runnable snippet that shows the problem you have.

Comment: Do you mean that 'dateAndTime' field is showing as null?

Comment: Also, what is `countdowntimer` ?

Comment: yes @Nitesh it shows me nothing

Comment: countdowntimer is a  function

Comment: *What* function is it? Did you make it yourself (show the code) or is it a plugin (which one)? What does "not working" mean? What happens and what did you want it to do?

Comment: No, Tell me about the jquery plugin you are using that provides coutdowntimer function?
IT must be passing some value but we need to know what type of value is expected in this function.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: The code you added doesn't seem to have anything to do with the countdowntimer method. Please read my previous comment and answer the questions I asked.

Comment: its a jquery countdown timer @JJJ it may be a jquery plugin

Comment: @AfzalKhan, I gave you an answer, check that, but before please answer me this: what is the value of `diff.date`? You said that when you alert `dateStr` it returns `23:5:58`, but in your code you have the date too. It is not being returned? I mean in this `var dateStr = diff.date + " " + diff.hours + ":" + diff.minutes + ":" + diff.seconds;`

Comment: the value of diff.date is the diff of days between todays date and the input date

Comment: @AfzalKhan, please create a https://jsfiddle.net which shows the exact problem you are having. Your question is missing relevant parts of the code, like the `HTML`.

Comment: i have update the code with the HTML

Comment: @AfzalKhan, the problem is `diff.date` It returns something like `1998` instead of a format like `2020/01/01`

Comment: OMG you are right